# MongoDB Compass - set a default sort

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

Nearly every time I open a collection in MongoDB Compass, I want to see the most recently updated record first. Is there a setting so that the data is automatically sorted this way, so I don't have to type `{lastUpdated: -1}` into the sort/options every time I look at a new collection?